# How to identify HSAT1 repeated sequences from the FASTA (contains only them but multi-stretches) files and compute the frequency of occurance?

Tags: bash, python

I am looking for something in a shell that helps me to first identify the patterns and then count them as how many times they are present. Importantly if I may be able to get the location start and end for these sequences as the header will be great!!!

To get familiar with the problem.

First I tried using `RepeatMasker` to mask the genome with the HSAT1 coordinates but did not go well. So I fetched the FASTA file that contains all the HSAT1 regions

Now for example,

```
acataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgtacataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgt
```

So the stretch is 10 times repeated here.

I wish to first detect that it is stretch as its variable and then count it with positions.

Outcome:

```
Chr17 acataaaatatcaaagtacacaaaatatatattatatactgt 10
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please restate your problem in computational terms rather than bio-something terms. Many of us here are not familiar with terms like FASTA, HSAT1, RepeatMasker. What's a "stretch"? Where did "Chr17" appear from in the outcome?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am a very new user and did not realize this. Thank you for editing my mistakes.

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question, the people there might actually understand what you need (alteast I don't)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Let me explain a bit and i think it would be more easy, So, I have a fasta file that is outcome of DNA sequencing, now in that file there is repeated sequences, what i need is to identify those repeated sequences based on its length and capture their cordinates and frequency of appearance.